# Why use an arbitrary versioning system with MAKEWORD instead of a simple int or string?

Tags: c++, winsock2

I've been learning how to use winsock recently and have been watching a series of videos on building a chat client and server, I noticed that the versioning used is this:

```
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
```

Why use this rather than using a simple integer or string value? I'm interested in why this choice was made and what it's function is as opposed to my suggestion of a string/int.

Comment: One guess is that this goes back to the dark ages of 16-bit Windows in the 1900's. The macro will put two values in a WORD, even if the definition of a WORD should ever change (never happened).

Comment: generally, don't expect too much sense from Win32 api. most of the stuff was written for backward and future compatibility.